# NAudio directSound.stop issue (?)

Tags: c#, naudio

Why is one more data chunk fetched from `WaveProvider` after I call *Stop* on `DirectSoundOut`? It happens even after a pause.

I am using NAudio 1.5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's just an artefact of the way `DirectSoundOut` has been written. It's open source so you can see the code [here](http://naudio.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/25e1ba2cce59#NAudio/Wave/WaveOutputs/DirectSoundOut.cs). You could probably stop this by putting a check for `PlaybackState == PlaybackState.Stopped` just after the call to `WaitHandle.WaitAny` in `PlaybackThreadFunc`.

Comment: Thx, I downloaded the code already but it is too complicated for me. Tomorrow expect questions about ASIO crashing my app :O